# Show if $I$ is an ideal then $I + I= I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I'm just wondering if this is as simple as just saying ideals are closed under addition.

Comment: Closed under addition means $I+I\subseteq I$. It doesn't mean $I+I=I$. There's one more step...

Comment: Equality follows if $0\in I$.

Comment: I may be over complicating it but shouldn't the other inclusion follow from being able to write any element of I as a sum of two other elements of I?

Comment: @Jeffrey Stats Yes, any $x\in I$ may be written as $x + 0$.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I knew I overthought that one.

Comment: @JeffreyStats Would you consider posting an answer to your own questions so that it doesn't drag on in un-answered limbo? Thanks